# What is a 'redirect URL' to distribute Slack bot?

Tags: python, heroku, slack, slack-api

I created a Python Slack bot hosted on Heroku (which works well on my personal workspace) but now wish to distribute it to other workspaces.

On the Slack 'manage distributions' page it requests at least one redirect URL. I do not understand what this is. For example: if the Heroku domain of my bot is `https://my-awesome-bot.herokuapp.com/` what would it's redirect URL be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect URL is part of your website to enable installation of your Slack app to other workspaces (e.g. via "Add To Slack" button) and therefore required to enable distribution.

The installation of Slack apps is done via the OAuth 2.0 protocol. How it works is that after the user of a workspace authorized your app to be installed by providing his Slack credentials, Slack will redirect the user back to your web site (using the provided redirect URL) so your app can get the new token for that particular workspace.

You can add your redirect URLs on the OAuth 2.0 & Permission section of your Slack app management page. The exact URL depends on how your website is structured.

Please see the documentation [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) on how the OAuth 2.0 process works with Slack.

Comment: So for Heroku, is the redirect URL the same as the domain URL? I have no idea of how Heroku is structured.

Comment: It depends on how you design your app, not on Heroku which is just a cloud platform. Normally you would have a special route just for the redirect (e.g. `/login`), but it can be anything. I would recommend to read up on how OAuth works with Slack.

Comment: I did go through the OAuth documentation. But it's about using web hooks. I don't use any. Problem is, I can't even get into my domain - comes out as 'Application Error' as my bot runs on a worker dyno. The bot works perfectly for my own workspace, however I wish to allow others to use it. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you need a web hook to make Oauth work. And you need som kind of storage to save the token to. That is the only way. But it does not have to run on the same domain like your app.

Comment: I think I answered your question as posted. If not please let me know. Otherwise I would appreciate if you could mark this answer as solution so we can close this question. TY!